# Stylecop custom rules does not show on settings

Tags: c#, stylecop

I created my own stylecop custom rules using C# express 2010, however when i put my .dll file in stylecop folder it doesn not show my custom rules in the stylecop settings list, may i know is it my coding issue or i misplace the files? below is my xml code kindly advice

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SourceAnalyzer Name="My Custom Rule3">
<Description>
Custom rule for demo purposes.
 </Description>
   <Rules>
    <Rule Name="AvoidUsingAInClassNames" CheckId="CR0001">
      <Context>Do not use 'M' letter in {0} names.</Context>
      <Description>Fires when 'a' letter is used in class name.</Description>
    </Rule>
  </Rules>
</SourceAnalyzer>
```

Comment: Have you placed the dll in correct folder? The build action for XML should be embedded resource. Can you check that?

Comment: Hi ram, 
   Thank you for your comment, i placed my stylecop custom rules in the stylecop v4.7 folder, and my xml changed the setting to embedded. but it still does not show on my stylecop settings list.

Answer (score 2):

Verify the dll versions. I had the same problem because my rules where developed using version 4.3, and 4.7 is under a different namespace:

**4.3:**

```cs
using Microsoft.StyleCop;
using Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp;
```

**4.7:**

```cs
using StyleCop;
using StyleCop.CSharp;
```

Answer (score 2):

The XML file should be named **exactly** the same as the class file so *MyClass.cs* & *MyClass.xml*.

You also need to ensure the class library is producing a v3.5 .NET DLL as well as making the XML an embedded resource and placing the DLL in the StyleCop folder.

Comment: Changing the target framework of the class library from .NET 4.5 to NET 3.5 worked for me.  I am using StyleCop 4.7.  Thanks.

Comment: +1 I went from .NET 4.5 to 4.0 thinking that would work. Nope.  Only when I dropped it down to 3.5 did my stuff start showing up.